# Include other .tpl in a .tpl file Prestashop

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I'm usinh a Prestashop 1.5.4.1, and I would like to call a module in other module (precisely I need to use slider module just above the home featured products). I tried to call it via

**include file='../directory/module.tpl'**

but always I get only blank page without any code. I also tried with different ways of directory statement, but always the result was the same. Is there any possibility to include new module in correct way?

Answer (score 5):

For this to work, your directory structure should be (Using PrestaShop 1.6):

```
-- mymodule.php
-- views
---- templates
------ hook
------ displayFooBarTemplate.tpl
-------- inc
---------- foo.tpl
---------- bar.tpl
```

**Absolute way:**

From your main module file:

```
protected function displayFooBarTemplate()
{
    global $smarty;

    ...

    $smarty->assign('module_templates', dirname(__FILE__).'/views/templates/');

    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'displayFooBarTemplate.tpl');
}
```

then in your tpl file (displayFooBarTemplate.tpl):

```
{include file="{$module_templates}hook/inc/modal/foo.tpl"}

{include file="{$module_templates}hook/inc/modal/bar.tpl"}
```

**Relative way (my favorite):**

```
{include './inc/foo.tpl'}

{include './inc/modal/bar.tpl'}
```

Comment: {include 'inc/foo.tpl'} did not work but {include './inc/foo.tpl'} did!!

Comment: What am I doint worng... {include file="$tpl_dir./modules/blockcategories/blockcategories.tpl"} -> in product.tpl . Why is the .tpl file for categories not loading ? Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me in Prestashop 1.6 is

```
{include file="$tpl_dir/modules/blocknewsletter/blocknewsletter.tpl"}
```

I put this in the footer.tpl file and correctly displayed the text box for subscribing to the newsletter. I suppose it works for all other modules, too.

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to include a smarty tag includes using the curl brackets.

```
{include file='directory/module.tpl'}
```

Note that the directory in the include statement should be relative to the templates directory.

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.include.tpl

Answer (score 0):

In your php code declare a variable like this :

```
$this->path_to_tpl_folder = str_replace('\\', '/', _PS_MODULE_DIR_) . 'mon_module/tpl';
$this->context->smarty->assign('tpl_path', $this->path_to_tpl_folder)
```

Then in your smarty template :

```
{include file=$tpl_path/my_file.tpl}
```

Compatible with Prestashop 1.4 and 1.5.